# How can I find an email I received that begins with a given text?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'm looking for an email I received within the last 7 days beginning with "oops there's a mistake in your order..."

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Search for

```
oops after:2016/9/21
```